# Bash scripting help

Tags: bash, scripts

I try to make a bash script that use tor, proxychains, and curl.
The first thing I want is to verify tor status and, if tor status is active, run `proxychains curl icanhazip.com`, then execute `proxychains firefox www.site.com`.

After that, close firefox and do it again, but this time, if the IP address is the same from the first `proxychains curl icanhazip.com` then run `service tor restart` and verify the IP address again. Otherwise, if the IP address has changed, execute `proxychains firefox www.site.com`.

This is my script :

```
#!/bin/bash
TORS=$(service tor  status | awk '(NR == 3) {print $2}')
curlip=$(curl icanhazip.com)
echo "$TORS"
if [[ $TORS = active ]] ; then
proxychains curl icanhazip.com
else
service tor restart
fi
```

From here I don't know how to contiune. Anybody can help me out?
I'm new here, I apologize if I posted the wrong way

Comment: you just want a new tor exit node ?

Answer (score 2):

Must be run with sudo because the script will restart the tor service
Be aware that icanhazip.com could 'hate' repetitive queries...
You may use [TorSocks](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/torsocks) for your needs of tor network.

```
#!/bin/bash
TORS=$(service tor  status | awk '(NR == 3) {print $2}')
## useless ## curlip=$(curl icanhazip.com)
echo "$TORS"
if [[ $TORS = active ]] ; then
  OldIp=$(proxychains curl icanhazip.com)
  NewIp=$OldIp
else
  while ["$NewIp" -eq "$OldIp"]; do
    service tor restart
    NewIp=$(proxychains curl icanhazip.com)
  done
fi
```

Comment: Thank you, and after that how I make to open proxychains firefox www.site.com and do this again and again.

Comment: why firefox? curl will do it well... And to give you an answer, just add a loop while 1=1 just after the while for new ip

Comment: Because whit this script I want to try to increase youtube views.

Comment: Cheating is wrong. YT views number is increased if vid is viewed, not only page loaded... Cheaters often buy clicks on the dark market... Cheating is wrong.

Comment: I want to do this for a friend who is new to the music industry. And if he reach a certain number of viewers on youtube it will broadcast the song on the radio. I want to help a friend

Comment: just add a line `proxychain firefox www.URL.com` after `done` and before `fi`. You will have to watch the vid and close firefox to get the script go ahead to the next viewing...

Comment: I try my best to help a friend. I know this is a wrong way. And I'm very thankful to you and anybody helps me to help my friend. Thank you I will try. Thank you again.